# Refinement of migration flag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred

I recently dug through the flags and stumbled over a rather small problem but I would like to address it none the less:

When you want to flag a post as offtopic because it's a pure programming question, which belongs to stackoverflow, or when someone asks a data request question, which belongs to open date SE, then I only have the option to migrate it to gis.metaSE

[image]

Using the same flag at Stack Overflow, it gives me more options:

[image]

My first thought was, that I am lacking reputation but I have less on Stack Overflow then here.

Can we add some common sites like Stack Overflow and Open Data SE so we can maybe speed up the process of migration?

SO and open data are the ones, which come to mind, but we could add many more.

Comment: moderators can migrate to any stack exchange site, this is just a flagging system to help deciding, at 10,000 rep you can see use moderator tools  https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @Mapperz That's true, but this particular flag is in my opinion rather useless without any other option besides meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with [@Midavalo's answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4621/115) that migration should be used sparingly, and that closing as Off-Topic with the close reason that it should be on a different site is a very workable alternative.

Also, we at GIS SE cannot implement this at our level, so if you really want it, then it needs to be implemented SE network-wide which means voting at [Migrate to *any* site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86928/migrate-to-any-site)

Personally, I would prefer to see a ["push-pull" model for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/186461/215590) implemented first.

Comment: thanks for your input! I wasn't aware, that this issue is at site level rather than the GIS SE level because I thought this would be a moderator thing.

Answer (score 4):

There is a different Off-Topic flag that I believe you should be using in this situation.  The flag you refer to is specifically for *migrating* questions from one SE site to another.  We don't migrate often.

Rather we prefer to close as Off-Topic with the close reason that it should be on a different site.  If the Asker requests that we migrate it, then someone with the access can migrate it to that site for them, otherwise they typically just ask it on that site themselves.

Look for the Close > Off-Topic reason that says:

> Questions relating to general IT or with no clear GIS component, are off-topic here but can be researched/asked at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (**software development**), [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (**computing hardware and software**), [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) (**relational databases**) and [other SE sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name)

This Close > Off-Topic reason can be found directly above the migrate flag you mention.

[image]

Comment: You have a valid point and in fact, I used this particular flag recently. But even if this flag is good enough for this particular reason you described. it renders the migration flag useless in my opinion. But as @PolyGeo pointed out, this isnt an issue you can solve on the GIS SE level.

Comment: @LaughU the migrate flag is there for community vote to migrate a question to Meta, as per your screenshot. This can and does happen. Once you have enough rep you have further options here.

Comment: Maybe its my lack of understanding the workflow which keeps me wondering. In any case thanks for clearing this up for me :)